# Spring WebFlux functions stop executing if system is loaded

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming

My code looks like this:

```
public Mono<Item> calculate (Item item) {
        return Mono.zipDelayError(
                        callSystemOne(),
                        callSystemTwo()
                .onErrorMap(err -> err.getSuppressed().length > 0 ?
                        wrapError() :
                        err)
                .flatMap(a -> callSystemThreeAndRemap()
                .map(this::fillSomeFields);
    }
```

All calls to other systems looks the same

```
    public Mono<String> callSystemOne() {
        return apiClient.makeCall()
                .flatMap(r -> isError(r.getMeta()) ?
                        Mono.error(() -> {                            
                            return wrappedError()})  :
                        Mono.just(r))
                .flatMap(service::validateResponse)
                .onErrorMap(remapToRequiredException);
    }
```

It works as intended. However, even under a small load, 1 RPS for example, callSystemTwo() might never happen.
callSystemOne() always works correctly; I see logs of its request and expected response.
On the other hand, for callSystemTwo(), sometimes I can't even see the initial apiClient.makeCall() request log. It looks like this function is skipped completely.
Perhaps, my program keeps waiting  forever until a retry happens.

I have retries configured on the Ingress side, and after a retry, all works fine. All three systems are called.
Ingress is not the problem, without it behavior is the same.
SystemTwo might not respond from time to time, but it does not explain, why i dont even have a request log.

I'm new to reactive programming, so any explanations why this might happen are much appreciated.